# How to use variable from variable group in conditional insertion expression in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

My aim is to use a variable group to hold global configuration settings which apply to all pipelines. Specifically, I want the ability to flip a switch in a variable value to switch from using hosted build agents to using private build agents instead.

I have a variable group named **my-variable-group** which contains a variable named **UseHostedAgents**. I can toggle its value between **true** and **false**.

The pipeline:

```
variables:
  - group: my-variable-group

stages:
  - stage: deploy
    pool:
      ${{ if eq(variables['UseHostedAgents'], 'true') }}:
        vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      ${{ else }}:
        name: private-pool
    jobs:
     ...
```

I can't figure out how to get this to work. It seems as though the variable group variable values aren't available in the conditional insertion expression. I've tried everything I can think of to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Been wrestling wit this for hours and I think it's impossible.  Conditional insertion relies on template syntax which is evaluated at compile time.   Couldn't find confirmation in the docs but you can see in the logs for a job `Job preparation parameters` where the variables from a group look like they're being mapped to environment variables using runtime expressions.  This means the variables in variable groups are available too late to be used for conditional insertion.  For my use case I gave up and hardcoded the variable as I don't need to change it that often.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable/parameter to store whether you want to run on custom agent pool or shared and use it.

Example with parameters:

```
parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string
    default: private-pool

variables:
  ${{ if eq(parameters.environment, 'private-pool') }}: 
    buildPoolName: private-pool
  ${{ else }}:
    buildPoolName: ubuntu-latest
```

And then on your job you should use the `buildPoolName`

```
- job: 'Job 1'
  displayName: 'Build'
  pool:
    name: $(buildPoolName)
  steps:
```

Comment: While this would work, it doesn't solve my requirement to have a single "switch" where I could failover all pipelines to use private rather hosted agent pools. What I don't understand is why I can't use values from a variable group to do what you've illustrated above...

Comment: You can use variables groups normally. Try to switch to `${{ if eq($(variableNAMEfromGROUP), 'true') }}:`

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just the syntax error, can you try this?

```
variables:
  - group: my-variable-group

stages:
  - stage: deploy
    pool:
      ${{ if eq(variables.UseHostedAgents, true) }}:
         vmImage: ubuntu-latest
      ${{ else }}:
         name: private-pool
    jobs:
     ...
```